# /usr/bin/env: ‘python\r’: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, python3, rosrun, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using WSL to write python code and then trying to run it from rosrun, this error code is encountered.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385421//usr/bin/env:-%E2%80%98python%5Cr%E2%80%99:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Victor_Kash](https://answers.ros.org/users/71808/victor_kash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2021-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem are your line ending characters. Your file was created or edited on a Windows system and uses Windows/DOS-style line endings (CR+LF), whereas Linux systems like Ubuntu require Unix-style line endings (LF).

There is a simple tool that can convert the two different styles for you called dos2unix.

Install it by running

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

After that, you can convert files in either direction using one of the commands

```
dos2unix /PATH/TO/YOUR/WINDOWS_FILE
unix2dos /PATH/TO/YOUR/LINUX_FILE
```

Example:

```
dos2unix tf_list_conversion.py
```

---

Originally posted by [Victor_Kash](https://answers.ros.org/users/71808/victor_kash/) with karma: 50 on 2021-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-30**:
Or use an editor which stores files in the target format.